# Removing selected option in multiple select2 clears all options

Tags: jquery-select2, laravel-livewire

Using Laravel livewire, bootstrap 5 modal and select 2.

Select2 (s2) without `multiple` works fine. It's populated, selections save to the component, clearing is also fine.

When an s2 has `multiple` attribute, removing a selected option clears all the options and nothing is displayed in the results drop down. When adding a selection, this doesn't happen.

If I do a `dispatchBrowserEvent` and re-init the s2 it does work again.

My question is why does removing an s2 option require a re-init but an add doesn't.
Seems to be something to do with the rendering in `render()`.

Some code...

Blade:

```
<div wire:ignore>
    <select id="selectedTrades" wire:model.defer="selectedTrades" class="select-2" multiple="multiple" data-field="selectedTrades" data-allow-clear="false">
    @foreach ($contractor_trades as $trade)
        <option value="{{ $trade['id'] }}">{{ $trade['name'] }}</option>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Standard stuff. wire.ignore around the s2. The modal has `wire:ignore.self`.

JS:

```
$('.select-2').on('change', function (e)
{        
    var $this = $(this);
    livewire.emit('setSelect2Property', $this.attr('data-field'), $this.val());
});
```

Component:

```
public function setSelect2Property($property, $value)
{
    $this->$property = $value;
}
```

Just sets `$this->selectedTrades` to the array sent.

Adding:

[image]

The drop down has the options as expected.

Removing:

[image]

The thin light line under it is the container for the results that's now empty. The original select element does still have its options.

If I remove the `livewire.emit` from the js to test, the s2 behaves correctly.

I think it has to do with the components `render` method. I can't figure out what is happening different when I add versus remove.

Comment: [Seems to work fine for me, at least in playground](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/724d8e1d-9582-4d80-8706-c0275efc64b9). I had to make some assumptions about how you organize your code.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work. The problem was the `dropdownParent` element I was using. I had it set to the modal. Setting it to the immediate parent element and it worked as expected.

Comment: Thx, this solves the problem within LiveWire components 